# How to use service in generic class (Angular 7)

Tags: angular, typescript, generics, angular7, wrapper

I have the following example:

Data model:

```
export interface SampleList {
    readonly Id: number;
    CompanyName: string;
    Country: string;
}
```

Component:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  private sampleList = new SampleWrapper<SampleList>();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sampleList.loadData('v_ListOfCompanies');
  }
}
```

Wrapper class:

```
export class SampleWrapper<T> {
    public changes: T;
    public original: T;

    private sampleSvc: SampleService;

    constructor() { }

    public loadData(dbView: string) : void {
        this.sampleSvc.getData<T>(dbView)
            .subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.original = data;
                },
                error => {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            );
    }
}
```

Service:

```
export class SampleService {

  static readonly apiUrl: string = environment.apiUrl;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getData<T>(dbView: string) : Observable<T> {
    const url = `${SampleService.apiUrl}/${dbView}`;

    return this.http.get<T>(url);
  }
}
```

The http-Requests fails, because `sampleSvc` is undefined.

> ERROR TypeError: "this.sampleSvc is undefined"

How can I use an ApiService in a wrapper class? Can anyone help me? Or give me some advice about using generic classes in typescript especially Angular 7?

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to inject the service using [`Dependency injection`](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection) within the constructor

```
 constructor(private sampleSvc: SampleService) { }
```

and then use it as,

```
 this.sampleSvc.getData<T>
```

Comment: I already tried that. But I get an error `error TS2554: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.` I'm not sure to set the SampleService as param in the initialization part.

Comment: that means you are passing wrong arguments to the service

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide your service inside of constructor

```
export class SampleWrapper<T> {
    public changes: T;
    public original: T;

    constructor(private sampleSvc: SampleService) { }

    public loadData(dbView: string) : void {
        this.sampleSvc.getData<T>(dbView)
            .subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.original = data;
                },
                error => {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            );
    }
}
```

And than you should extends your class instead of create new istance of it

```
export class AppComponent extends SampleWrapper<SampleList> implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadData('v_ListOfCompanies');
  }
}
```

But the best way is to use `export class SampleWrapper<T>` as service if that component does not have any view.

Comment: I'm getting an error when I initialized the Wrapper class => `error TS2554: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.`

Comment: But I have more Interfaces.. Lookups for dropdowns. I can't set all these lookups in the extends-Statement.

Comment: I have asked if SampleWrapper component has a view if not, it for sure should be a service then you do not have to extend.